# Coveo automatic atomic facets for integer values?

Tags: atomic, facet, coveo

I have a Year facet on a Coveo search page that's manually defined

```
<AtomicNumericFacet
  field="searchnewsyear"
  label={labels.facetSearchNewsDate}
  sortCriteria="descending"
  display-values-as="link"
>
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2030" end="2030" endInclusive="true" label="2030" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2029" end="2029" endInclusive="true" label="2029" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2028" end="2028" endInclusive="true" label="2028" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2027" end="2027" endInclusive="true" label="2027" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2026" end="2026" endInclusive="true" label="2026" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2025" end="2025" endInclusive="true" label="2025" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2024" end="2024" endInclusive="true" label="2024" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2023" end="2023" endInclusive="true" label="2023" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2022" end="2022" endInclusive="true" label="2022" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2021" end="2021" endInclusive="true" label="2021" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2020" end="2020" endInclusive="true" label="2020" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2019" end="2019" endInclusive="true" label="2019" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2018" end="2018" endInclusive="true" label="2018" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2017" end="2017" endInclusive="true" label="2017" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2016" end="2016" endInclusive="true" label="2016" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2015" end="2015" endInclusive="true" label="2015" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2014" end="2014" endInclusive="true" label="2014" />
  <AtomicNumericRange start="2013" end="2013" endInclusive="true" label="2013" />
</AtomicNumericFacet>
```

I want to make this automatic rather than hardcoded, but when I tried to make it generate the facets automatically, it generates them as weird decimal ranges.

```
<AtomicNumericFacet
    field="searchnewsyear"
    label={labels.facetSearchNewsDate}
    sortCriteria="descending"
    display-values-as="link"
></AtomicNumericFacet>
```

Is there a way to get it to automatically generate the facets as integers (and not ranges)?

[image]